# RStudio: After the execution of a command, the cursor jumps to the console and stays there

Tags: console, rstudio

I've tried a few things out in RStudio and must have changed some settings accidentally. 
Every time I execute a command now, the cursor jumps to the console. If I do not shift it back to the script, it stays in the console, which is quite annoying because I want to continue writing the script instead of working in the console. Does anybody know how I could change that?

Comment: Are you using R-studio? If so that should be noted in the question.

Comment: Are you using RStudio or the base R GUI? How exactly are you executing your commands? What version of R and your editor are you usuing?

Comment: Yes I am using Rstudio, thanks for the hint!

Comment: I use the newest version of R and RStudio (I don't use R GUI).  I execute the commands via CTRG + Enter, but it doens't make a difference if I use the Run-button instead

Comment: @MrFlick  Do you migth have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. In [this page](https://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/1.3.399-1/session-user-settings.html) you can read about session user settings. For me `focus_console_after_exec` was missing, so I appended it to the end of `rstudio-prefs.json`.

Here is [another page](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State) where you can find out where your `rstudio-prefs.json` is located.